# Есть ли решение улучшить интерфейс Calendar View?

Tags: android, calendar-view

Стандартный `Calendar View` включает в себя только плитку с выбором даты, ещё можно пролистывать месяцы, но, согласитесь, пролистывать по месяцу лет, скажем, 30 — удовольствие ниже среднего. Есть ли решение, в котором можно было бы пролистывать годы? И чтобы в момент пролистывания менялся год в `Calendar View`?

Приблизительно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делал такую реализацию добавлением поля `EditText` с `android:inputType="number"`

в коде:

```
CalendarView cv = ваш CalendarView;
EditText year = ваш EditText;

 year.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (year.getText().length() == 4) {
                Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
                date.setTimeInMillis(cv.getDate());
                date.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(year.getText().toString()));
                cv.setDate();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```